# Check connection with internet not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an Android app with Phonegap. I need check if an internet connection is "true". If is false, show an alert, "else" redirect to website.
But not working, it seems that the app simply ignores this "script".

code:

```
<head>
<script>
var state = navigator.connection.type;
if (state == window.Connection.NONE)
{
  alert("nao");
}
else
{
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://website.com.br/abc" />
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean [`window.navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine)

Comment: I'm a web developer, but I have a suggestion which might work. Try making an ajax request with jquery and use the timeout attribute. If the request times out then chances are that the user doesn't have a connection. Again there could be a better way. Good luck :-)

Comment: In my var state? @adeneo

Comment: @www139 You can help me, writing an answer with an example?

Comment: you have to wait for the device ready before using navigator object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function in my `Android`/`Phonegap` Application:

```
function CheckConnection() {
      if(!navigator.network) {
          navigator.network = window.top.navigator.network;
      }
      // return the type of connection found
      return ( (navigator.network.connection.type === "none" || navigator.network.connection.type === null || navigator.network.connection.type === "unknown" ) ? false : true );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how call this function? Sorry, I'm newbie with javascript.

Comment: Call it like this: `CheckConnection();`. You may also want to call it via button click or an interval (have it call the function every whatever seconds). I have never had to deal with this type of situation before. If the answer above works I think it would be your best bet. It (I believe would be the most reliable answer if it works [which I don't know because I'm not familiar with that code])

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that this may not be the most reliable. Also you don't want to confuse a slow connection with no connection so the timeout attribute must be set for a long period of time for slow connections. I also use jquery for the ajax request because the javascript would be a lot of code so make sure you have the jquery library on hand. First create a php file to make a request to (I'll call it test.php):

```
<?php
//test.php
echo 'request success';
?>
```

The initiator for the request (checks your internet connection):

Javascript/Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
        alert('no internet');
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
        //success function do this if the request is a success
    },
    timeout: 30000 // sets timeout to 30 seconds remember you want it to be long to ensure that it isn't just a slow connection
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps and again it may not be the best way. I'd think that java might have a method/class to see about internet. I'd also think that you are using java since this appears to be an Android app--Correct? Tell me if this didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in **cordova ver >= 3.0.0** then first you need to install Network Connection plugin using **CLI**(*Command-Line Interface*), which events added by **org.apache.cordova.network-information**

1. online
2. offline

**cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
   document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
});

function onOffline() {
   // YOUR CODE FOR OFFLINE
}

function onOnline() {
   // YOUR CODE FOR ONLINE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using an [experimental API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) and that's why its not working.

As you are developing on PhoneGap then you have to **add** the corresponding plugin to retrieve network info.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

check details and examples of this plugin [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md).

once you added the plugin, now to test network connection.

```
var state = navigator.network.connection.type;
        if (state == navigator.network.connection.type)
        {
          alert("nao");
        }
        else
        {
          <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://website.com.br/abc" />
        }
```